# Scraping dinamic data from web app using Scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from this website: https://www.icostats.com. The problem is that it looks like the data is dinamically generated with JS.

I'm using ScrapyJS to fetch data from the columns (e.g. 'Change(%)') and export it to a json file. So far, I can't get anything other than `[{"text": null}]` as output. Am I messing up or is this not doable?

My code:

```
import scrapy

class ICOSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "icoo"
    allowed_domains = ["icostats.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://icostats.com',
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={
                'splash': {
                    'endpoint': 'render.html',
                    'args': {'wait': 0.5}
                }
            })

    def parse(self, response):
        for ico in response.css('div#app'):
            yield {
                'text': ico.css('div.data-reactroot container-0-16 table-0-20 tableheader-0-50 tr-0-68 td-0-69 tdName-0-73::text').extract_first(),

            }
```

Crawling command: `$ scrapy crawl icoo -o ico.json`

Comment: Yes. Use google chrome console to see where the javascript is requesting its data from, you can then make  the same call in Python. Alternatively, you'll have to use something like Selenium to run the JS and extract values.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/1F0E4 I can see that it's pulling the data from some sort of API. Here is where the requests are going to: https://icostats.com/graphql

Comment: You are using `data-reactroot` as a `class` but what, exactly, is its status? I could barely see it in a Chrome inspection window but in copying the code into here — `<div data-reactroot="" style="display: flex; height: 100%;">` I can see that it's an attribute.